# In-App Purchase for Hardware-As-A-Service

Tags: in-app-purchase

We are currently working on a Hardware-As-A-Service model in which we are going to sell our hardware products with a monthly subscription.

The customers will first buy this subscription from our website and when they receive the hardware, they will have to use the application on the App Store in order to login with their credentials and be able to control the hardware. If for any reason the subscription is not renewed the application will block the access to the customer and therefore they won't be able to use the product.

Our app doesn't have premium services, however the hardware and app are not usable without the subscription. The question here is, is it a must to have an In-App Purchase through the application or can I just rely on the website to manage the subscriptions?

Thank you for the help.